# Why my CSS file is not being registered in functions.php?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I want to enqueue the stylesheet in `functions.php`, but it's not loading. What can be problem in my code?

```
function my_theme_sty() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_s', 'my_theme_sty' );
```

Comment: There is no `admin_enqueue_s` hook in WordPress.

Comment: Thanku sir now it working ,i was forget to use the hook..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function should be:

```
function my_theme_sty() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_sty' );
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two useful [action hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/actions/) for registering / enqueuing external scripts & styles in WordPress:

### 1. `wp_enqueue_scripts`:

[`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) is the proper action hook to use when enqueuing scripts & styles for the front end.

So if you want to add the CSS file on the frontend of the site, then your CODE will be like:

```
function my_theme_sty() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_sty' );
```

### 2. `admin_enqueue_scripts`:

On the other hand, [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) is the proper action hook to use when enqueuing scripts & styles for the admin panel.

So if you want to add the CSS file on the admin panel of the site, then your CODE will be like:

```
function my_theme_sty() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_sty' );
```